# A combinatorics problem on a triangle

Tags: combinatorics

Given a triangle $ABC$ and $n$ points $A_{i},\,i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ scattered along its perimeter.

How many (different) triangles can we form

(a) with vertices out of the set of points $\{A_{i}\}-\{A,B,C\}$ 
under the restriction of choosing one vertex from each side of $ABC$

(b) with vertices out of the set of points $\{A_{i}\}-\{A,B,C\}$ (with no restriction)

Comment: By circumference, do you mean the circumference of the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$?

Comment: @Aaratrick Probably means points are on the perimeter

Comment: I mean along the triangle's perimeter